# LibGDX - Color Picker

Tags: android, user-interface, opengl-es, libgdx

How to implement `color picker` in LibGDX like below:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically you would have an `Image` with the texture in your question, and detect `touches/drags` over it. Once you know the coordinates you're on, and having the `Pixmap`, you can know the color code with.-

[public int getPixel(int x, int y)](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html#getPixel(int,int))

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmmm... I didn't think about it! Thanks!